# Java API to create BigQuery job taking too much time

Tags: java, optimization, google-bigquery

I have simple query to run and it takes 1 sec to run when run from google console. But when I run it from my java code it takes too much time to get result. I have done clustering on i_col1, p_col1 and p_col1Id.

Query looks like below:

```
WITH d as (select p_col1, p_col2 as col_num from sit.table3)
SELECT a.col1, a.col2, b.test_col1, c.col_test1 FROM sit.table1 a
inner join sit.table2 b
 using (i_col1) 
inner join sit.table3 c
 using (p_col1) 
left join d on a.p_col1Id=d.p_col1 where ( trDate between '2023-05-25' and '2023-05-25' );
```

But when same query run using java API com.google.cloud.bigquery package, it takes around 6.5 sec.

```
JobId jobId = JobId.of(UUID.randomUUID().toString());

JobInfo jobInfo = JobInfo.newBuilder(jobConfiguration).setJobId(jobId).build();
Long startTime = DateTimeUtils.currentTimeMillis();
Job job = bigQuery.create(jobInfo).waitFor();
log.info("------------Total time to create job: ----------"+(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
```

This gives output as below:

```
[2023-05-30_17:46:00.697] [main] INFO  c.h.g.p.o.s.t.BQReadService - ------------Total time to create job: ----------6572
```

I am not able to understand how to optimize this.
**So Job job = bigQuery.create(jobInfo).waitFor(); this statement taking almost 6.5 sec to return 1922 rows.**
I want to show result in frontend table such delay at this level leads to sluggish response for user even though using BigQuery.

Let me know if there is way to improve this. Also let me know how I can improve query as well.

Comment: How does your hardware and system resources compare to Google?

Comment: @aled this microservice is on premise hosted and its communicating using service account with GCP.

Comment: @aled Do you think anything can be changed to optimize performance?